# How to convert temperature units {Celsius-->Kelvin, etc} from weather API on toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openweathermap

I am using Openweather API , to fetch data like units, weather report, etc. I am trying to create a toggle where the temp changes on clicking as per the toggle button. Like Celsius to Kelvin, etc.
In below code I am trying to pass units to URL and using SegmentedControl(it is a React component package) to use the toggle UI. But the value (value: "standard", etc) that I am using is not able to pass in the units of the URL (`` const url = `https://api.openw..... ``). I am not able to figure out how I can pass the value to the units in the URL so that temperature changes automatically without going through any mathematical equations.
I have omitted some of the code lines for better visibility.

```
export default function Home() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState("");
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");
  const [units, setUnits] = useState();
    const apiCall = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const loc = e.target.elements.loc.value;
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${loc}&appid=${apiKey}&units=${units}`;
    const req = axios.get(url);
    const res = await req;
    setWeather({
      descp: res.data.weather[0].description,
      temp: res.data.main.temp,
      city: res.data.name,
      humidity: res.data.main.humidity,
      wind: res.data.wind.speed,
      feel: res.data.main.feels_like,
    });

    setCity(res.data.name);
  };
  const Weath = () => {
    return (
      <div className="container">
    {" "}
        <div>
          <div>
            <Text mr="xs">Units:</Text>
            <SegmentedControl
              value={units}
              onChange={setUnits}
              data={[
                {
                  value: "standard",
                  label: (
                    <Center>
                      <Box>Kelvin</Box>
                    </Center>
                  ),
                },
                {
                  value: "metric",
                  label: (
                    <Center>
                      <Box>Celsius</Box>
                    </Center>
                  ),
                },
                {
                  value: "imperial",
                  label: (
                    <Center>
                      <Box>Fahrenheit</Box>
                    </Center>
                   ),
                },
              ]}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="top">
          <div className="text-left">
            <div className="flex gap-2">
              <p className="text-2xl  ">{weather.city}</p>
              <CiLocationOn size={25} />
            </div>
            <div className="text-7xl font-bold">
              {weather.temp}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       .
       .
      .
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
     <div className="app">
      <div className="search">
        <form onSubmit={apiCall}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="city" name="loc" />
          <button className="bttn">Search</button>
        </form>

        {weather && <Weath />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am expecting to change the temperature as per the given option/toggle.

Comment: I can see you are not using double quotes in unit useState may be its not converting part of unit while making a right url

Comment: Even after using  const [units, setUnits] = useState("metric"); it does not provide desired result.